# Showing that probability of random variable is greater than another random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let X1, X2, . . . be a sequence of independent identically distributed continuous random variables.
For n ≥ 2, define Xn as a record of the sequence if Xn > max(X1, X2, . . . , Xn−1),
that is, if Xn is larger than each of the values observed so far.

(a)Find the probability that X2 is a record. Use symmetry to obtain the answer without
computation; ans = 1/2

b) Find the probability that Xn is a record, as a function of n. Again use symmetry.
(Answer: 1/n)

c) Find a simple expression for the expected number of records that occur over the first m
trials for any given integer m (X1 is not considered as a record). Show that this number
is infinite in the limit m → +∞.
(Answer: Pm
k=2 1/k → ∞ as m → ∞)

For Question a, I know we have to evaluate P(X2 > X1) and this simplifies to $\int_{- \infty}^{\infty} P(X_2>x)P(X_1=x)dx$. I'm not sure how we can use symmetry. Any hint will help.

For quesiton b, this looks like a generalisation of part a, Except $P(X_n>max(X_1, X_2, .. X_{n-1})) = P(X_n>X_i)^n $

Not sure for part c.

d) Let $N_1$ be the index of the first record in the sequence. Find P(N1 > n) for each n ≥ 2.
(Answer: 1/n)

My solution: N1$\sim Geo(1/n)$

P(N1 > n) = $(1 - \frac{1}{n})^n(\frac{1}{n}) + (1 - \frac{1}{n})^{n+1}(\frac{1}{n})+..$

= $(1 - \frac{1}{n})^n(\frac{1}{n})( 1+ (1 - \frac{1}{n})+(1 - \frac{1}{n})^2+.. = (1 - \frac{1}{n})^n$ by GP formula.

Comment: $N_1$ is not geometrically distributed.  It is not the count of failures before success in a sequence of *independent and identically* distributed Bernoulli trials.

Comment: The event $\{N_1=n\}$ is the event that no sample exceeds the first sample until trial $n$. That is that among $n$ samples the maximum and next maximum are the last and first, respectively. $$\mathsf P(N_1{=}n)=\mathsf P(X_n{>}X_1{>}\max{(X_k)}_{k=2}^{n-1})$$

Comment: PS: the answer is *not* $1/n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathcal R_n$ be the event that $X_n$ is a record.  That is the event for $X_n=\max\{X_1,..,X_n\}$.

$(a)$ Well, we know $(X_n)_{n\ge 1}$ are i.i.d (independent and identically distributed).   By symmetry each sample thereby has equal probability for being the maxiumum among the first two, so $\mathsf P(X_2=\max(X_1,X_2)) = \frac{1}{2}$.$$\mathsf P(\mathcal R_2)=\tfrac 12$$

$(b)$ Since $(X_n)_{n\ge 1}$ are all i.i.d, then following a similar pattern could find $\mathsf P(\mathcal R_3) = \mathsf P(X_3 {=} \max(X_1,X_2,X_3)) = \frac{1}{3}$.   We find a pattern and see that, as there is no bias as to which sample has the maximum value among the first $n$ samples, the probability will be $\frac{1}{n}$ for $X_n$ being a record. 
$$\mathsf P(\mathcal R_n)=\frac 1n \qquad=\mathsf P(X_n{=}\max{\{X_k\}}_{k=1}^n)$$

$(c)$ So now we want the expected count of records among the first $m$ trials (discounting the first). Let us use indicator random variables for the events, so that count is $\sum_{n=2}^m \mathbf{1}_{\mathcal R_n}$, and we seek its expectation.   We know that $\mathbb{E}(\mathbf 1_{\mathcal R_n}) = \mathsf P(\mathcal R_n).$ So by Linearity of Expectation: $$\mathbb{E}\left(\sum_{n=2}^m \mathbf{1}_{\mathcal R_n}\right) = \sum\limits_{n=2}^m \dfrac 1n$$

Comment: You mean $\mathbb E( \sum_{i=1}^n 1_{X_i\text{ a record}}) = \sum_{i=1}^n 1/i$, where $1_E$ denotes the indicator random variable for event $E$ (i.e. $1$ if $E$ occurs, $0$ if not).

Comment: Yes, this makes sense - i'll re-edit thanks

Answer (score 0):

For (a) and (b) use symmetry.  They are equally distributed and random therefore any one of them is equally likely to be the largest, so the probability that it is the $n^{th}\ is\ \frac{1}{n}$.

For (c) limit you may need a condition that $ F(x) \lt 1,\ for\ finite \ x$.  Otherwise a variable $X_n$ could be at the maximum and none $(k\gt n)$ could be greater.

Comment: These being continuous random variables, the probability that $X_n$ is at the maximum is $0$.

Comment: But they are all equal with probability 0

Comment: No, @RobertIsrael, they are *a sequence of samples of a continuous random variable*.  Although the probability for any one to have an exact value is of zero measure, one from among the first $n$ samples *will* almost certainly be *the* maximum of whatever values they do have, and each sample has equal probaility for being that one.  (There is negligible probability for a tie event.)

Comment: @GrahamKemp The "maximum" I'm writing of is the one that herb steinberg was worrying about in the second paragraph of his answer above, i.e. the maximum (if it exists) of the support of the distribution, a value $x$ for which $F(x) = 1$.  If some $X_n = x$, it is impossible to have any further maxima.  But the probability of this is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

For (a), $X_2$ is a record if and only if $X_2$ is the greatest of $X_1$ and $X_2$.  By symmetry, each of those has equal probability of being the greatest.

Similarly for (b), each of $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ has equal probability of being the greatest of those $n$, and $X_n$ is a record iff it is the greatest.